# If a set of random vectors are independent then would the join event of the random vector from the set and another random variable independent?

Tags: classification, probability, naive-bayes-classifier, naive-bayes-algorithim

If all x_i from i=1 to n are independent. And y_i is dependent on x_i. Then can we always say that all (x_i, y_i) tuples are always independent of each other? x_i is a random vector of shape mx1, y_i is a scalar.